# Maven execution to perform several plugins in sequence

Tags: maven-2

I'm working on something that is using Hibernate for database access. I've got everything set up and working so that I can use mvn hibernate3:hbm2ddl to build the database schema, and I'm using mvn liquibase:update to populate initial data into the database (DBUnit was my first try but I couldn't get it to work with Oracle and Liquibase just worked first time).

My problem is that if I execute hbm2ddl to drop and re-create the schema then the Liquibase DATABASECHANGELOG tables are left intact, meaning that Liquibase won't re-create the data the next time it's run. To get around this I've configured up mvn sql:execute to perform a drop on the two tables in question, but this means that to be safe if I want to build the database from scratch I now need to execute "mvn hibernate3:hbm2ddl sql:execute liquibase:update"

What I'd really like is to be able to configure up something that will execute the sql:execute command when the hibernate3:hbm2ddl command is run, so that I know that doing that one command will leave me in a nice clean database state. Failing that, a configuration that will run a number of commands in sequence automatically, so I could configure up for example "mvn execute:db-rebuild" to run the three commands above automatically.

I've seen mention of mojo-executor but no examples on actually how to use it. I'm not even sure if it's the right tool for what I want...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you bind these different things to a particular thing like the integration-test phase. The order of the plugins will define the order of exectutions. Than you get rid of hand calling mvn ...

Comment: Ok - I've actually read up on integration-test now that I'm on a real computer, and it actually looks like it'll do exactly what I want.